# Exit code 137 when running SonarQube analysis on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have a project with hundreds java modules.
I run SonarQube 5.1 with following plugins:

- Java 3.3
- Findbugs 3.2
- Checkstyle 2.3
- PMD 2.4.1
- Issue Assign 1.6
- SQALE 2.6
- SVN 1.1
- LDAP 1.4
- JIRA 1.2
- Cobertura 1.6.3

I use jenkins 1.639 with SonarQube plugin 2.3.

I set a job with the following settings:

- Goals :
  `$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.jdbc.url=$SONAR_JDBC_URL -Dsonar.jdbc.username=$SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME -Dsonar.jdbc.password=$SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD -Dsonar.log.level=DEBUG`
- MAVEN_OPTS: `` -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx8192m` ``

When I perform an analysis with Jenkins I get the following error:

```
<code>[INFO] [08:57:22.023] Store results in database
[DEBUG] [08:57:22.029] Execute org.******.batch.phases.GraphPersister
[DEBUG] [08:57:22.126] Execute org.******.batch.index.SourcePersister
[DEBUG] [08:57:28.263] Updating semaphore batch-com.mycompany.myapp:myapp
[DEBUG] [08:57:38.265] Updating semaphore batch-com.mycompany.myapp:myapp
[DEBUG] [08:57:48.267] Updating semaphore batch-com.mycompany.myapp:myapp
[DEBUG] [08:57:51.788] Execute org.******.batch.index.ResourcePersister
[DEBUG] [08:57:51.788] Execute org.******.batch.index.MeasurePersister
[DEBUG] [08:57:58.269] Updating semaphore batch-com.mycompany.myapp:myapp
[DEBUG] [08:58:08.271] Updating semaphore batch-com.mycompany.myapp:myapp
ERROR: Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 137</code>
```

Can you help?

Comment: This appears to be a Jenkins/OS issue. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989653/jenkins-maven-build-137-error

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's fixed now. See the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue before, but for me the lack of virtual memory of my linux instance was the issue.

Increasing the memory Maven options didn't help much

Comment: Correct. We have increased the physical memory from 16GB to 24GB. The problem has disappeared.