# AWS EC2 t2.micro Unlimited | Jenkins Maven | Very slow | Build hangs

Tags: performance, maven, jenkins, amazon-ec2, instance

I have an EC2 t2.micro instance with RHEL 8. I have installed Jenkins, created a Maven project, connected git repository. I run the build, it goes through the first few steps....then hangs and does not respond at all, then I have to stop and start the instance again. If I leave it hanging, the build comes back with :

"Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 137"

and the build fails. I have T2 Unlimited on the instance so I don't understand why this is happening?
I see a lot of people running maven builds multiple times through Jenkins on t2.micro instances...

I run the exact same on t2.small and it runs fine...but my frustration is with the t2.micro...

Comment: Yo have a memory problem. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989653/jenkins-maven-build-137-error. The unlimited only afects the CPU, not the memory

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that thread, it explains a lot. So I take it there is noway to deal with the t2.micro issue other than change it to a bigger instance. I find it very strange that other people with the same configuration using the same git repository can run this build multiple times with no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the EC2 instance type from t2.mirco to t2.small or t2.medium, which have more memory and the maven build runs just fine.

Answer (score -1):

That is because at first you define the url domain when you create your admin jenkins user. Then when you stop and start or restart, ec2 instance changes its URL and ipv4  and DNS of your EC2 will proccess how find the new URL. To solve this you must change the url on Jenkins config ( Manage jenkins / System / Jenkins location )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The issue appears to be about lack of memory not the inability to communicate with the worker node. The build wouldnt complete the first few steps of the build as described by the OP in this case?  If i had to guess, the solution to this issue (of running a process with a high memory requirement on a low memory system) would be to "right-size" the instance, or enable enough swap space. Increasing swap space would be lower performance but not cost extra. Increasing the instance size would double the hourly instance cost but would perform better than swap space.